# force ssl in tomcat 7

Tags: security, maven, ssl, tomcat7

I want to force all users to use SSL for all pages in my application. I am using mavan 3 and used this plugin in maven:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                <keystoreFile>-- My keystore path --</keystoreFile>
                <keystorePass>-- My keystore pass --</keystorePass>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

On running the server through maven (mvn tomcat7:run), my server logs are like this:

```
...
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 16, 2012 9:55:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 16, 2012 9:55:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
```

However, when I access the page with https, I get SSL connection error in chrome and "SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length." in firefox.

1) I believe maven embeds Tomcat 7 in the war. So, there is no server.xml file where I can manually configure SSL. How can I configure SSL in my pom.xml?

2) How to make sure that all requests get forwarded to 8443?

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that the "server" attribute may be causing your problem. According to the Tomcat plug-in documentation that is not an option. Here is a (very hard-to-find) list of the plug-in options for the Tomcat 'run' command. http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html Good luck. I had a similar problem, although not the same. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should configure SSL for Tomcat 7: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Then, you need to add server.xml to this embedded Tomcat, started by the plugin: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#serverXml

Then, forwarding from 8080 to 8443 should be done by your application internally, probably in servlet listener]. See also: [How to implement a HTTPS login page in a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454021/how-to-implement-a-https-login-page-in-a-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so i hosted the Tomcat separately then configured the ssl certificate in `server.xml` by generating jks file using JDK keytool.
So, all application can be hosted in same tomcat with secure https link.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="1500" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="C:\apache-tomcat-8\conf\filename.jks" keystorePass="password"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" > 
</Connector>
```

Add the above code in `server.xml` file and do the port forwarding from 8443 to 443.